# how to draw text on curve in c# windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am working on windows store app project for windows 8.1 in visual studio 2013. I need to apply curve on textblock using slider value.Means when i move slider the text becomes curved. Can any one help me for this.

Is their any simple way to curve text in xaml or c# for windows store app.

Comment: Check these articles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30090/Text-On-A-Path-in-WPF).

Comment: I tried to work with textonpath assembly, but with this assembly i also need to refer some more dlls like presentation core.dll,presentation framework.dll,windowsbase.dll, but it creates problem of mismatching target processor. so i need some easy solution.

Comment: can anyone please help, i need it now.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also struggling with it.
And all WPF solutions don't seem to work in WINRT (W8.1)